# Android Sliding Menu using Navigation Drawer class cast exception?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, slidingmenu

Whenever I want to use Sliding menu using Navigation Drawer then give me Error ClassCast Exception.

I dont know What is the my Mistake?
Actually Problem solving try to find out on Google and Change Code Related it. But I am not able to Solve the Error. Please See my code and Guide me What and where is error in my code.
Please Suggest me.
Thanks in Advance.

I Attach the code.

**Java File**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private LinearLayout llDrawerLauyout;
    private ListView slidermenu = null;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        slidermenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.slidermenu);
        llDrawerLauyout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llDrawerLauyout);
        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_launcher, // nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for
                                    // accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for
                                    // accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /***
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(llDrawerLauyout);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

**XML File**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llDrawerLauyout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="500dp"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:background="#6A57A9"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="#4D1212"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/slidermenu"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:background="#FF00FF"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="#FF0000"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Error LogCat**

```
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205): Process: com.example.slidingmenu, PID: 19205
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.slidingmenu/com.example.slidingmenu.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323)
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerView(DrawerLayout.java:1100)
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1305)
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at com.example.slidingmenu.MainActivity.displayView(MainActivity.java:188)
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at com.example.slidingmenu.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:115)
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2323)
05-04 15:38:03.694: E/AndroidRuntime(19205):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please share exception log.

Comment: Could you please post yours log cat errors???

Comment: @KrunalIndrodiya  
Please see my Updated Question

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha  
Please see my Updated Question

Comment: what is at line `MainActivity.java:188`?

Comment: put both the listview outside the frame layout.

Answer (score 0):

check you have "android-support-v4.jar" file in libs folder of project or not if its not copy the .jar file from sdk path "sdk\extras\android\support\v4" then clean the project and run.

Answer (score 0):

Use these line of code...

```
android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
```